# How to name an integer with a string name?

Tags: c++

I want to have a function making a new integer like this:

```
void makeInt(string str, int x);
void makeInt(string str, int x) {
  int str = x;
}

int main() {
  makeInt(name,4);
}
```

But now the question is, how can I make the string, name the integer? So that int name = 4. Because now it would only give out an error. Is that actually possible?

This is by the way in C++

Comment: you are passing the string to `makeInt()` by value. Consider changing the interface of your function to `string makeInt(int)` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, use C preprocessor macro.

```cpp
#define makeInt(str, x) int str = x

int main() {
  makeInt(name, 4);
}
```

Other than that, there is no way to do that in C++.

But I can't see any reason why would you want to do that.

If you want to store a variable with name inputted from user, and then retrieve the variable with name inputted from user, consider using `std::map<std::string, int>`.

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
  std::map<std::string, int> values;
  values["name"] = 4;
  std::cout << values["name"];
}
```

will prints `4`.

Comment: ... Why downvoted? Is it incorrect? If so, please post another answer.